# https для всего кроме одного каталога

Tags: nginx, http, веб-сервер, https

Подскажите как мне правильно настроить конфиг сервера на `Nginx`, нужно чтобы сайт работал на https НО чтобы все что в папке downloads скачивалось по `http` (обязательно по `http`, можно и `https`), но так чтобы весь сайт работал по `https` (редиректом с `http` на `https` кроме файлов в папке downloads), а также чтобы работали поддомены например `docs.example.com` и `telemirta.example.com`, настраиваю конфиг так:

```
server {
server_name          www.example.com;
listen               *:80;
listen               [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

if ($uri !~* ^/downloads/(.+)$) {
    return 301 https://example.com/downloads/$1;
}

}

server {
listen *:80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;


server_name example.com *.example.com;
root /var/www/html/$subdomain;
set $subdomain "";
if ($host ~* ^([a-z0-9-\.]+)\.example.com$) {
    set $subdomain $1;
    return 301 https://$1.example.com$request_uri;
}
if ($host ~* ^example.com$) {
    set $subdomain "";
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

if ($uri !~* ^/downloads/(.+)$) {
    return 301 https://example.com/downloads/$1;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /munin/ {
        alias /var/cache/munin/www/;
}


}

server {
listen *:443 ssl;
listen [::]:443;

server_name example.com *.example.com;
root /var/www/html/$subdomain;
set $subdomain "";
if ($host ~* ^([a-z0-9-\.]+)\.example.com$) {
    set $subdomain $1;
}
if ($host ~* ^example.com$) {
    set $subdomain "";
}

index index.php index.html index.htm;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example_com_crt.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/example_com.key;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
#rewrite ^/(downloads) http://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
rewrite ^/downloads/(.+)$ http://example.com/downloads/$1 permanent;

location /munin/ {
        alias /var/cache/munin/www/;
}

location ~* \.php$ { try_files $uri = 404; include fastcgi_params;
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
 }

}
```

сам сайт работает по `https` все ок, php работает, поддомены работают, но вот когда перехожу на `http://example.com/downloads/testarch.zip` или `http://example.com/downloads/testfi.amx` то получаю ответ от браузера

```
Страница недоступна  
Сайт example.com выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз.  
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

а если пробую перейти на `http://example.com/downloads/` то редиректит на `https://example.com` (на главную)
Помогите разобраться пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Если очистить конфиг от лишней логики решение очень простое.

Уберите папки для поддоменов. Использовать просто `root /var/www/html/$host;` предпочтительней.

`if ($uri !~* ^/downloads/(.+)$) {` - уберите эти ифы. проще ж с `location`

http server:

```
location /downloads {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

https server:

```
location /downloads {
    return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```